# NVidia Driver Issue MacBook Pro via Virtualbox

Tags: drivers

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1  on my macbook pro via Virtualbox and for some reason I can not get my NVidia GeForce 9400M driver to install. What are the necessary steps to install this driver? 
 I have tried to install the Drivers via Software Center but have had no luck. I even tried a few sudo commands but after trying I realized they were for Windows host based systems.
 Could someone please instruct me on how to install this driver?

Thank you all in advance!
iz

Comment: How can you expect to install nvidia drivers in a Virtualbox VM?

Answer (score 1):

Sine Ubuntu is installed in VirtualBox, it can only see virtual hardware, and thus, installing your real hardware drivers on your guest OS running in your VirtualBox makes your no sense at all.

You can verify what your hardware does your Ubuntu installation has access to by running your `lspci` command from your Ubuntu terminal.